# How to take away spaces between images?

Tags: html

I'm new here and I want to write my own site. I do NOT use CSS now, but I want to use it in the future once I figured out how it works.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to Nielyboyken</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="grey">
</p><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lbg3tjE57KYsx1"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jbg3tjE57KYsx1.png" border="0"/></a><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lp2vEndNDv7vj"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jp2vEndNDv7vj.png" border="0"/></a>
<br><img src="http://i.minus.com/iI7VEHhLP3WyV.png"</a> <center><font style="font-family: Fixedsys;font-size: 35px;color:blue">Welcome to this mini-forum!</font></center>
<br><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lbfBWr7hEsMtsT"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jbfBWr7hEsMtsT.png" border="0"/></a><center><font style="font-family:Fixedsys;color:white">Welcome to this mini-forum. Notice that this is not a forum site but just a personal site.</font></center>
<br><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lb0OadHbWfnpew"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jb0OadHbWfnpew.png" border="0"/></a>
<br><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lbhDDFKmGlL4rk"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jbhDDFKmGlL4rk.png" border="0"/></a>
<br><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lMNcGJ5Bjwvx4"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jMNcGJ5Bjwvx4.png" border="0"/></a>
<br><img src="http://i.minus.com/i6nJ7Pg8kUfqo.png"</a>
<br><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lFNcJv4UvSdye"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jFNcJv4UvSdye.png" border="0"/></a>
<br><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lshbphpEbNRi2"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jshbphpEbNRi2.png" border="0"/></a>
<br><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lhJnSHKv3vAco"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jhJnSHKv3vAco.png" border="0"/></a>

</body>
</html>
```

The images must stay on the left side under each other.
And when I try to write something and center it, I get a much bigger space.

Comment: Using CSS **is** the solution. You'll have to learn it to solve your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two divs, side by side, using float.  [Here is a link to where I took a shot](http://dansdemos.info/clips/democss.html).

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to Nielyboyken</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="grey">
<style>
#header{
width:100%;
margin 0 auto;
}
#wrapper{
width:100%;
float:left;
}
#left{
width:15%;
float:left;
}

#right{
width:500px;
float:left;
text-align:center;
}

</style>
<div id="header"><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lbg3tjE57KYsx1"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jbg3tjE57KYsx1.png" border="0"/></a><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lp2vEndNDv7vj"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jp2vEndNDv7vj.png" border="0"/></a>
<br><img src="http://i.minus.com/iI7VEHhLP3WyV.png"</a>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="left">
<a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lbfBWr7hEsMtsT"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jbfBWr7hEsMtsT.png" border="0"/></a>
<br><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lb0OadHbWfnpew"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jb0OadHbWfnpew.png" border="0"/></a>
<br><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lbhDDFKmGlL4rk"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jbhDDFKmGlL4rk.png" border="0"/></a>
<br><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lMNcGJ5Bjwvx4"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jMNcGJ5Bjwvx4.png" border="0"/></a>
<br><img src="http://i.minus.com/i6nJ7Pg8kUfqo.png"</a>
<br><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lFNcJv4UvSdye"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jFNcJv4UvSdye.png" border="0"/></a>
<br><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lshbphpEbNRi2"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jshbphpEbNRi2.png" border="0"/></a>
<br><a target="_blank" href="http://minus.com/lhJnSHKv3vAco"><img src="http://i.minus.com/jhJnSHKv3vAco.png" border="0"/></a>
</div>
<div id="right">
<font style="font-family: Fixedsys;font-size: 35px;color:blue">Welcome to this mini-forum!</font>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```